# packaging different dependencies in one rpm file

Tags: rubygems, dependencies, rpm, packaging

I want to install chef inspec. I know that can be done using `gem install inspec` but i want to create a rpm file from this gem. I also want to put all the dependencies of `inspec` together in this rpm package. How can I do that? One way is to use `fpm`. I have created a tar file and put all the dependencies there and used `fpm -s dir -t rpm -n "inspec" /path to tar file/`. It creates a rpm file `inspec-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm`. But when I run `rpm -ivh inspec-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm`, it gives `error: unpacking of archive failed on file /path to tar file: cpio: chown failed - Operation not permitted`. What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You gem2rpm to create the package. And package all dependencies separately (you will thank me later).

You can even use this Copr repository:
https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/g/rubygems/rubygems/

where is this package already built:

- https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/g/rubygems/rubygems/package/rubygem-inspec/
- https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/g/rubygems/rubygems/build/378921/

Comment: Thanks @msuchy. but it gives `failed dependencies error` on installing it. I used this package https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/@rubygems/rubygems/fedora-24-x86_64/00378921-rubygem-inspec/rubygem-inspec-0.27.0-1.fc24.noarch.rpm